# Page design and Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, layout

I'm looking for a Tikz code, which can draw "canons of page construction" in a background of document.
Please take a loot at:
[Modern book design, margins and typed area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55502/modern-book-design-margins-and-typed-area/55719#55719)

I know geometry and layout packages, but this is not exactly what I want.

http://retinart.net/graphic-design/secret-law-of-page-harmony/

Comment: You can start e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475601/194703). What precisely do you mean by "Tiitz"?

Comment: Do you want the same background image on every page?  If yes, use the background package.  If not, look at everypage and tikz.